# Destructor called more than 10000 times in mc++

Tags: c++

I am working on Code written in MC++(managed extensions of c++)
I know destructor is converted to Finalize after compilation.

But when executing sample, that finalize is invoked more than 10000 times.
That call displayed in Debug log file is like  :-

```
 Finalize() - Entry
 Finalize() - Exit

 Finalize() - Entry
 Finalize() - Exit
 .
 .
 .
 .
 & so on..
```

I want to know the reason for these multiple finalize calls.
what can be the probable causes for it ?

These multiple calls to finalize are shown in my Debug logs. 
Also, Is it a good practice to place Debug logs inside destructor(finalize)
when coding in mc++ ?

The destructor code is like :-

```
 ~Destructor()
 {
     //Debug Entry log
     .......
     if(condition)
     {
          //some code
     }
     else
     {
          ReRegisterForFinalize(this);
     }
    //Debug Exit log
 }
```

Also, GC::ReRegisterForFinalize(obj) method adds current obj to finalization queue for finalization. Now after calling this method, exactly after how much time the finalize will be called ? whether finalize will be called immediately or it is indeterministic ?

Comment: How can anyone possibly answer this question unless you include some of your code?

Comment: Where are you calling ReRegisterForFinalize? ReRegisterForFinalize can cause an object to be finalized more than once, even if it has already been finalized. Look at the example for that method on MSDN. If you call it in the destructor, your object might be finalized many times.

Comment: @Botz3000 ReRegisterForFinalize  is called inside the destructor. But if an object is finalized, why it should be called again ? Also, should we place debug logs inside destructor or not ? I mean, is it good pratice to place debug logs inside destructor ?

Comment: @kapilsharma If you need to log something that happens in your destructor then it's good practise to put logging in your destructor. What other answer did you expect? There are no special rules as far as destructors and logging goes.

Comment: @john Thanks for the answer. I was working on a bug that is related to log file. Due to these multiple finalize calls log size is quite large(in MB's). Thats why my concern was logs.

Comment: 'But if an object is finalized, why it should be called again ?' I think the answer to that is because you called 'ReRegisterForFinalize'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NOTE: This is assuming you are indeed using Managed Extensions for C++, as your question suggests, and not C++/CLI, as your tags suggest. If you are using C++/CLI instead, things are completely different.

The finalizer is called because of your call to `ReRegisterForFinalize`.

When an object has a finalizer, it will be automatically added to the finalization queue, you don't have to do that yourself. When the object is ready for finalization, the finalizer can be called by the runtime at some (undefined) point (or by you, using `delete`). Now when you call `ReRegisterForFinalize`, you tell the runtime that it should call the finalizer **again**, which can repeat for any number of times.

When you are in the finalizer, your object *is already being finalized*, so a call to `ReRegisterForFinalize` doesn't make sense (unless you have a very special reason for it).

Comment: Thanks for the  answer :)

Comment: One more thing i want to ask, when executing the same dot net sample in cmd and vs2010, the order of destructor calls differs. what could be the reason for this ?

Comment: @kapilsharma When running via visual studio, such things can be different because you are debugging the application. The order of destructor calls is not defined, so they can be called in any order. Visual studio might have to keep some objects alive for a bit longer to enable debugging.